# How to capture and replace items in tokens with html

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to parse text like this

```
<! this is inside a token > text outside the token <! more inside > more outside
```

and I want to capture all the tokens and replace them with `<span>...</span>` tags.

For instance

```
<! this is inside a token >
```

should get replaced with

```
<span> this is inside a token </span>
```

I tried regex  `/<!(.+)>/` but it just captures the whole string.

Comment: See also the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `<!([^>]*)>` with `<span>$1</span>`

Check [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8AHFn/).

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
/<!([^>]+)>/
```